# SQL Oracle | How to DELETE from a table that changes its size

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I have a table call TRANSACTIONS. I'm trying to delete not all the transactions from the table. So it could be like this:

**DELETE FROM** TRANSACTIONS tr
**WHERE** tr.Id != "123456"

But the problem is that I don't know the transactions that are not going to be delete. So sometimes my query could be like this

**DELETE FROM** TRANSACTIONS tr
**WHERE** tr.Id != "123456" **AND** tr.Id != "23566"

or this

**DELETE FROM** TRANSACTIONS tr
**WHERE** tr.Id != "123456" **AND** tr.Id != "23566" **AND** tr.Id != "222222"

And I want to put it into a STORE PROCEDURE. How can I find a way to make this procedure?

Comment: It looks very odd that you delete all the transactions except a few. And "transactions" table with "delete" are bad companions: if you really want to delete everything except few records, it would be better to move required data to additional table, truncate original table and move data back to original table.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create additional table which will contain `ID` values you want to keep:

```
create table keep_id (id number);
```

Query which deletes all rows but `ID`s stored above would then be

```
delete from transactions a
where not exists (select null
                  from keep_id b
                  where b.id = a.id
                 );
```

If you want to create a procedure out of it, no problem - just enclose it into

```
create or replace procedure p_del_transaction as
begin
  delete from transaction ...
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
```

Then you can use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_transactions(
  i_except IN string_list
)
IS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM transactions
  WHERE id NOT MEMBER OF i_except;
END;
/
```

and call it using:

```sql
BEGIN
  delete_transactions(string_list('123456', '23566', '222222'));
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=93261a6a0bdcff22e451afda0cd42b37)*